# How I download two different extensions files without opening in the browser?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am uploading .doc/docx or .pdf files and I want it to download without opening it in to the browser.

```
if(file1 == null)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("CustomError", "Please Select Word or PDF file");
                return View();
            }
            if(!(file1.ContentType == "application/doc" || file1.ContentType == "application/pdf" || file1.ContentType == "application/docx" ))
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("CustomError", "Please Select .doc or .pdf file only");
                return View();
            }
```

```
public FileResult Download(string file1)
        {
            string filename = file1;
            string Path1 = Server.MapPath("~/Files");
            string FullPath = Path.Combine(Path1, file1);
            byte[] fileBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(FullPath);

            return File(fileBytes, "application/pdf");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this overload of the `File` method to download the document as a file instead of opening it in the browser:

`return File(fileBytes, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet, filename);`

Using the generic octet-stream MIME type means the browser won't try to interpret the file type to decide whether to display it or download it as a file.